# Некорректно отображается сайт с телефона

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, iphone, safari

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему неправильно отображается верстка сайта с iPhone, когда захожу на него именно через  Safari?

Я только что сделал сайт, проверил адаптивность внутри wordpress - всё сделано правильно. Решил проверить, как выглядит сайт с телефона, зашел в safari и вот так я вижу главную страницу.
Однако, если захожу через приложение Яндекса или через Chrome, то сайт отображается корректно.

Вот сайт - https://kroppa.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что сафари. С ним вечно проблемы. Если у тебя есть девайс с сафари - так в нём и выясняй что ему не нравится.

Comment: Проще не стало) Ладно буду искать) Думал кто-то уже сталкивался с таким